# Get and set position with jQuery .offset()

Tags: jquery

How to get and set the position of an element with the jQuery `.offset` method?

Let's say I have a div `layer1` and another `layer2`. How can I get the position of `layer1` and set the same position to `layer2`?

Comment: Denise, did you even check the .offset() method on jQuery website? Also, why don't you accept Steve's answer below?!

Comment: @Rafid she basically never came back

Comment: Can I have her points?

Answer (score 201):

```
//Get
var p = $("#elementId");
var offset = p.offset();

//set
$("#secondElementId").offset({ top: offset.top, left: offset.left});
```

Comment: You can just pass the entire `offset` object, so the `//set` would become:  `$("#secondElementId").offset(offset)`

Comment: hey! how can I set to bottom and right of div? there's no bottom,right property in offset

Answer (score 34):

I recommend another option. jQuery UI has a new position feature that allows you to position elements relative to each other. For complete documentation and demo see: http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/#option-offset.

Here's one way to position your elements using the position feature:

```
var options = {
    "my": "top left",
    "at": "top left",
    "of": ".layer1"
};
$(".layer2").position(options);
```

Comment: This answer was voted down twice, with no explanation. Please do tell why, if you down vote my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe that's because you use jQuery UI while the OP asks only jQuery.

Comment: often people go tooooo far with the down voting. Lets not assume that a wider answer is useless to others even if it may be an expansion of the OP. Don't get me started on the 'closed as this is not a proper question' ;)

Comment: @KSev - I'm from the future. jQuery still does not have a setter on `.position`... See: https://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: @Koshinae It's part of jQuery "UI". See the link above or try http://jqueryui.com/position/. Also, if you're using jQuery, you may want to consider using angularJS 2.0. However, I expect you're maintaining legacy code.

Answer (score 16):

It's doable but you have to know that using `offset()` sets the position of the element relative to the document:

```
$('.layer1').offset( $('.layer2').offset() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option. This is just for the x coordinates.

```
var div1Pos = $("#div1").offset();
var div1X = div1Pos.left;
$('#div2').css({left: div1X});
```

Comment: offset().left and css.left are not same thing, they may or may not have the same values depending on the page structure.

Comment: I +1'd. It seems to work just fine for me and It is essentially the same as the unchosen answer below that has 85+ votes.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks for the contribution!

Answer (score 0):

```
var redBox = $(".post");

var greenBox = $(".post1");

var offset = redBox.offset();

$(".post1").css({'left': +offset.left});
$(".post1").html("Left :" +offset.left);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/va836/159/