# Setting the offset on <li>

Tags: jquery, html-lists, offset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get and set position with jQuery .offset()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613261/get-and-set-position-with-jquery-offset)

Is possible to set the offset on a li?

I have 3 `<li>`'s inside a `<ul>`

And i want to change their positions with jquery.
I want to be able to set their positions according to the values stored in cookies.

for example:

```
$('#saved3').offset({left: $.cookie("moved3left")});
$('#saved3').offset({top: $.cookie("moved3top")});
```

If i *alert* the cookies, it alerts the value right...

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: @j08691 it's <ul> <li> content </li> <li> content </li> <li> content </li> </ul> basic..

Comment: @undefined no, because i can set other elements, just cant set this ones

Comment: Yes I realize that, however I wanted to see how you were using your IDs.

Comment: you can see it @ rumonet.pt/index2.php the <li> can be moved, but i wanted to set their offsets on page start, with cookies

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#saved3').offset({
  top: +$.cookie("moved3top"),
  left: +$.cookie("moved3left")
});
```